# Doubts on Same Origin policy?

Tags: html, web-applications, same-origin-policy

I went thru http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy and got some doubts on same origin policy.
Say i hit an URL `http://myApp1:8080/myApp1` and see welcome.html on browser. Now i try to submit the welcome.html form (or try to make an ajax 
call )to different application i.e `http://myApp2:9001/myApp2`. Will this call be  able to hit myApp2 server. As per my understanding
browser itself will not send this call to myApp2 because of Same Origin policy. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Will this call be able to hit myApp2 server.

Yes

> As per my understanding browser itself will not send this call to myApp2 because of Same Origin policy. Is that correct?

The Same Origin Policy prevents JavaScript on one origin from reading an HTTP response from another origin. It doesn't prevent the request from being sent (except when the situation triggers a [preflight request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#preflight-request)).

Comment: You mean to say that if i send an request to app2 from app1 for  some data update (no data retrieval), it will work  but if i send a request to app2 for retrieving some data, server code at app2 will be able to set the data under response but javascript will not be able to read that response. Is that right?